# Можно ли хранить название класса сущности в БД (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Есть сущность Video. Хочу разделить на FileVideo, YoutubeVideo и ещё несколько. Чтобы у каждой сущности была своя реализация getUrl() и getPreview(), но хранились все в одной таблице.

Можно ли это сделать стандартными инструментами Laravel? Чтобы можно было написать Video::all() и сразу получить коллекцию из сущностей с разными классами. Как вариант, хранить название сущности в отдельном столбце в БД.

Читаю документацию по 6-ой версии и нигде не вижу ничего подобного.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: @РустамГимранов это понятно, вопрос в другом. Как заставить Eloquent при вызове Video::all() возвращать объекты FileVideo, а не Video. Собственно ответ я уже нашёл.

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл ответ. Нужно переопределить методы newInstance и newFromBuilder, получилось следующее:

```
public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false, $class = null)
{
    if(!$class)
        $model = new static((array) $attributes);
    else
        $model = new $class((array) $attributes);

    $model->exists = $exists;
    $model->setConnection(
        $this->getConnectionName()
    );
    $model->setTable($this->getTable());
    return $model;
}

public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
{
    if(empty($attributes->type))
        throw new Exception('Видео должно иметь атрибут type.');

    if($attributes->type === 'file')
        $class = FileVideo::class;
    elseif($attributes->type === 'youtube')
        $class = YoutubeVideo::class;
    else
        throw new Exception('Некорректный тип видео: ' . $attributes->type);

    $model = $this->newInstance([], true, $class);
    $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);
    $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());
    $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);
    return $model;
}
```